# Create wrapper with unknown data types

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a wrapper in T-SQL for a procedure where I'm not sure what the data types are. I can run the wrapper without an `INSERT INTO` statement and I get the data just fine, but I need to have it in a table.

Whenever I use the `INSERT INTO` I get an error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

I've parsed back through my code and can't see where any column names don't match up, so I'm thinking that it has to be a data type. I've looked through the procedure I'm wrapping to see if I can find what the data types are, but some aren't defined there; I've referenced the tables they pull some data from to find the definitions; I've run `SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY` on all of the data to see what data type it is (although some of them come up null).

Is there some better way for me to track down exactly where the error is?

Comment: Provide actual code please.

Comment: "wrapper" is `INSERT ... EXEC`?

Comment: I could post the wrapper code, but I'm not sure that would be helpful without the 3000 lines of code from what I'm wrapping. Below I found a workaround to answer my own question, but to clarify, my "wrapper" consists of declaring all the parameters in my procedure the same as the wrapped procedure, then executing that procedure with an EXEC followed by that same list of parameters. In between the two is a "DECLARE @ReportSet TABLE" with all the fields and data types I expect from the wrapped procedure, plus "INSERT INTO @ReportSet".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find out your stored procedure result schema, using [sp_describe_first_result_set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602(v=sql.110).aspx) (available from SQL2012) and [FMTONLY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspx). Something like this:

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set
    @tsql = N'SET FMTONLY OFF; EXEC yourProcedure <params are embedded here>'
```

More details can be found [here](https://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/new-metadata-discovery-features-in-sql-server-2012/).

However, if I remember correctly, this works only if your procedure used deterministic schemas (no SELECT INTO #tempTable or similar things).

One trick to find out the schema of your result is to actually materialize the result into ad-hoc created table. However, this is not easy since `SELECT INTO` does not work with `EXEC procedure`. One work-around is this:

1) Define a linked-server to the instance itself. E.g. loopback

2) Execute your procedure like this (for `SQL 2008R2`):

```
    SELECT * INTO tempTableToHoldDataAndStructure
    FROM OPENQUERY(' + @LoopBackServerName + ', ''set fmtonly off exec ' + @ProcedureFullName + ' ' + @ParamsStr
```

where

```
@LoopBackServerName = 'loopback'
@ProcedureFullName = loopback.database.schema.procedure_name
@ParamsStr = embedded parameters
```

For `SQL2012` I think the execution might fail if RESULT SETS are not provided (i.e. schema definition of the expected result, which is kind of a chicken-egg problem in this case):

```
' WITH RESULT SETS (( ' +  @ResultSetStr + '))'');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I get more familiar with T-SQL I'm sure I'll be back to try it out, but for now it's a little over my head. I found a low-tech, slow solution that worked--posted below.

Comment: I did try your first suggestion. I did not write the procedure I'm wrapping, and it's definitely over my head. Here's the error message I got:
"Msg 11514, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_first_result_set, Line 1

The metadata could not be determined because statement 'EXEC *EXTGEN_SpName
         *ContextName
         , *UserName
         , *SessionID OUTPUT' in procedure 'InitSessionContextWithUserSp'  contains dynamic SQL.  Consider using the WITH RESULT SETS clause to explicitly describe the result set."

Those "*" characters were really "@" but it wouldn't let me post like that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have a solution to my problem. It's tedious, but tedious I can do. Randomly guessing is what drives me crazy. The procedure I'm wrapping dumps 51 columns. I already know I can get it to work without putting anything into a table. So I decided to comment out part of the select statement in the procedure I'm wrapping so it's only selecting 1 column. (First I made a copy of that procedure so I don't screw up the original; then I referenced the copy from my wrapper). Saved both, ran it, and it worked. So far so good. I could have done it line by line, but I'm more of a binary kind of guy, so I went about halfway down--now I'm including about 25 columns in both the select statement and my table--and it's still working. Repeat procedure until it doesn't work any more, then backtrack until it does again. My error was in identifying one of the data types followed by "IDENTITY". I'm not sure what will happen when I leave that out, but at least my wrapper works.